# Other Admin except Super admin can access provisioning api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-provisioning-api

i am developing an app.i am using google provisioning api in this app.in documentation it is mentioned that admin account can acces provisioning app.there are various types of admin accounts in google apps for example
1.Super Admin

2.Groups Admin

3.User Management admin

4.Help Desk Admin

5.Services Admin

in these all profiles in which accounts we can enable provisioning api .please reply

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom role and assign it permissions from the Provisioning API section (at the very bottom of the list of possible permissions. Delegated users who are granted rights to perform actions in the Control Panel will not be able to perform the same actions via the API unless explicitly assign Provisioning API permissions for their role.

See [this help article](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2406043) for more details.

Jay